# Twilio Programmatic Voice not working

Tags: rest, api, permissions, request, twilio

I am exploring Twilio. Successfuly enabled sms sending but have troubles with programmable voice callbacks. As I understand from the developer console https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/api-explorer/voice/calls (POST section) all I need to do is to run this code to receive callback:

```
curl 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-0401/Accounts/my_account/Calls.json'
-X POST \ --data-urlencode 'From=Twilio_generated_phone_nuber' \ -u 
some_hash:[AuthToken] --data-urlencode 'To=MY_NUMBER'
```

But I get only this response:

```
{
   "code": 21215,
   "message": "Account not authorized to call +MY_NUMBER. Perhaps you 
    need to enable some international permissions:
    https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international",
    "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21215"
}
```

**Pay attention please**: I had this error previously while configuring sms sending. I resolved this after enabling all countries including my own from this list https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international . After that sms function works fine. For now I can't get callbacks, and error message recommend me to go to the same page (international) and enable permissions but I have done this already while configuring sms.

I thought that sms and callbacks products have different pages for configuring countries permissions, but no they haven't. Well at least I didn't find it :)

Help please! 
Thanks for checking the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is indeed a page for international permissions for voice calls too. You can find it here: https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/settings/geo-permissions

Comment: I'm getting error 21215 for a Kenyan beta number I just bought, when trying to call a Kenyan mobile. The geo-permissions settings section doesn't include Kenya as an option. Am I missing something? Looks like Twilio sold me a Kenyan calling number, but I can't get approval to call Kenyan numbers?

Comment: Hey @Sitati, can you email me with your account SID at philnash@twilio.com and I'll see if I can help.